# Java: How to get while loop to only output last line

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, fibonacci

Just beginning to learn java so this has had me stuck for quite some time now. This is a program to output numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. The goal here is to get the program to output only the last line of the while loop. I've got the program up and running, just having trouble trying to figure out how to only output the last line of the sequence

Example Input/Output
Input: 5

Output:
Fibonacci #3 is: 3
Fibonacci #4 is: 5
Fibonacci #5 is: 8

Output should look like this: 
Fibonacci #5 is: 8

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Fibonacci2 {

    public static void main(String args[ ]) {

       int n, 
           counter = 2, 
           sum,    
           prevN, 
           nextN; 

       String inputValue;

       inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number Greater than 2: ",
                              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
       n = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);

       if (n >= 2)

       counter = 2; 
       prevN = 1;
       nextN = 2;

       if (n < 2) 
       System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");


       while (counter < n)
       {
           sum = prevN + nextN;
           prevN = nextN;
           nextN = sum; 
           counter++;

           System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum); 

       }

       System.exit(0);

    } 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried just moving the `System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum); ` to just above the `System.exit(0);` statement (outside of the loop)? I'm also concerned about your `if` statements, not using `{ }` to contain the context means only the next line will be execute when `true`, which doesn't seem to be your intent

Comment: I've tried that, it gives me this: Fibonacci2.java:62: error: variable sum might not have been initialized
       System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum);                      
                                                          ^

Comment: The change `sum,` to `sum = 0,` when you create the variable references

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is, move the `System.out.println("Fibonacci #" + counter + " is: " + sum);` statement outside of the `while-loop` context...

```
while (counter < n) {
    sum = prevN + nextN;
    prevN = nextN;
    nextN = sum;
    counter++;
}

System.out.println("Fibonacci #" + counter + " is: " + sum);
```

> I've tried that, it gives me this: Fibonacci2.java:62: error: variable sum might not have been initialized System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum); ^

Unlike instance fields, local variables are not assigned a default value when you create them, so you need to ensure that the value has a default value if the path of the code can not guarantee it will be set...

```
int n,
        counter = 2,
        sum = 0,
        prevN,
        nextN;
```

Additionally, your `if` statements are of concern...

```
if (n >= 2)

counter = 2; 
prevN = 1;
nextN = 2;

if (n < 2) 
System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
```

Basically what this is saying is...

- if `n` is greater or equal to `2`, then `counter` equals `2`
- `prevN` equals `1`
- `nextN` equals `2`
- if `n` is less then `2` then print error message
- Continue to run loop

To me, this doesn't make a lot of sense and is difficult to read.  Instead, you should contain the code which should be executed for each branch within it's own execution context (ie, between `{...}` braces), for example...

```
if (n >= 2) {
    counter = 2;
    prevN = 1;
    nextN = 2;

    while (counter < n) {
        sum = prevN + nextN;
        prevN = nextN;
        nextN = sum;
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("Fibonacci #" + counter + " is: " + sum);
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
}
```

Which makes the code easier to read and to understand - but I'm simple minded

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Didn't think it would be such a easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

Just put it outside loop

```
while (counter < n){
sum = prevN + nextN;
prevN = nextN;
nextN = sum; 
counter++; 
}
System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, only to give me this error:                                       
       Fibonacci2.java:62: error: variable sum might not have been initialized
       System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum);
                                                          ^

Comment: @JakeSchlott At the start you have to give value to sum, because if n = 0 while loop is not going to happen so sum is not initialized. At the start make `int sum = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is to take outside of the loop the System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum) that way it only prints the last number; 
Like this:

```
while (counter < n)
   {
   sum = prevN + nextN;
   prevN = nextN;
   nextN = sum; 
   counter++;
   }
System.out.println("Fibonacci #"+counter+" is: " + sum);
```

Comment: When I put it outside the loop it gives me an error message saying that the variable sum has not been initialized.

Comment: When you declare sum do it like this: int sum = 0; you have int sum;

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar program for my EGR class; its goal is to output a number given a position (sequence begins at 1) i.e. p1=1, p2=1, p3=2, p4=3, p5=5, p6=8, etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the Fibonacci Number's position.");
long n=keyboard.nextLong();
long sum, prevN=1, nextN=0, counter=1, last=0, lastnum;


    while (counter <= n) {
        sum = prevN + nextN;
        prevN = nextN;
        nextN = sum;
        if (n == counter)
        {
             System.out.println("Fibonacci #" + counter + " is: " + sum);
        }
        counter++;      
    }
    
    

}}
```

I know that it's way late for OP but that's my two cents for any other students/enthusiasts looking for assistance.